# get div OR img element with in #wrapper with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I simple want to select the first element (to get the width) in my `<div id="wrapper">`, but I don't know yet if that is going to be another `<div>` or a `<img>`. Can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To retrieve the first child element of your `#wrapper`, you could do it like this:

```
var el = $('#wrapper').children(':first'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [**`:first-child`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/%3afirst-child)

The `:first-child` CSS pseudo-class represents any element that is the first child element of its parent.

in jQuery,

```
$('#wrapper:first-child')
```

Comment: There should be a space between `#wrapper` and `:first-child`, otherwise it will select the first element with the ID `wrapper` from it's parent

Answer (score 0):

You can use [:first-child Selector](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/)

```
 $("#wrapper:first-child" )
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do `$( "#wrapper" ).children().first();`